# Duplicate local variable "attach" error?

Tags: java

I'm trying to debug a section of the code, but there is a "duplicate local variable" error. How would I get around fixing this? I'm not sure what the error is, so I'm asking here.

```
public JumpPlusPlayer(JumpPlus plugin, Player p) {
    loadPermissions(p, plugin);
    fillConfig(plugin);
  }

  protected void loadPermissions(Player p, JumpPlus plugin) {
      HashSet<PermissionAttachmentInfo> perms = new HashSet<PermissionAttachmentInfo>();
    PermissionAttachment attach;
    if (plugin.usingPEX) {
      PermissionUser user = PermissionsEx.getUser(p);
      String world = p.getWorld().getName();
      attach = new PermissionAttachment(plugin, p);
      for (String perm : user.getPermissions(world)) {
        String expression = user.getMatchingExpression(perm, world);
        perms.add(new PermissionAttachmentInfo(p, perm, attach, user.explainExpression(expression)));
      }
    } else {
      perms = (HashSet<PermissionAttachmentInfo>) p.getEffectivePermissions();
    }

    for (PermissionAttachmentInfo attach : perms) {
      String perm = attach.getPermission();
      if (perm.contains("jumpplus.config.")) {
        String[] aux = perm.split("jumpplus.config.");
        aux = aux[1].split("-");
        if (aux[0].equals("hspeed"))
          this.hSpeed = Double.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(aux[1]));
        else if (aux[0].equals("vspeed"))
          this.vSpeed = Double.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(aux[1]));
        else if (aux[0].equals("maxjumps"))
          this.maxJumps = Integer.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(aux[1]));
        else if (aux[0].equals("maxfreejumps"))
          this.maxFreeJumps = Integer.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(aux[1]));
        else if (aux[0].equals("jumpcost"))
          this.jumpCost = Integer.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(aux[1]));
        else if (aux[0].equals("fallmodifier"))
          this.fallModifier = Integer.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(aux[1]));
        else if (aux[0].equals("particleeffect"))
          this.particleEffect = Boolean.valueOf(Boolean.parseBoolean(aux[1]));
        else if (aux[0].equals("defaultstate"))
          this.enable = Boolean.valueOf(Boolean.parseBoolean(aux[1]));
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Paste here stacktrace of error, show line of code throwing it.

Comment: A decent IDE can help you (http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)

Comment: @defaultlocale It's a compile error so there won't be a stacktrace.

Comment: Search the code for `attach`. How does it relate to the error message?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist sorry, didn't read post carefully

Answer (score 2):

> How would I get around fixing this?

Um, don't declare a local variable twice in the same scope?

Either use a different local variable name in your enhanced for loop, or move the declaration of the first one into the `if` statement:

```
PermissionAttachment attach = new PermissionAttachment(plugin, p);
```

(You don't *use* it outside the `if` statement, so why declare it at the start?)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your `loadPermissions` method, in particular these two lines:

```
PermissionAttachment attach;
for (PermissionAttachmentInfo attach : perms) {
```

The first line declares a local variable (a variable that only exists inside that method invocation) named `attach`. The second line *also* declares a local variable named `attach`, but since that already exists it can't do so. You need to pick a different name for one of them.